# What is the broadcast rate for WSM in the DSRC standard?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am using OMNET++5.6.2 and veins5.2, to develop a clustering algorithm.

The algorithm is implemented by the RSU that broadcasts a list of possible CHs using WSM over one of the service channels.

I used a broadcasting rate of 0.1s,

like the BSM for the WSM and the WSA that announced the service.

However, after a certain time, the vehicles stop changing state to CH.

The RSU kept broadcasting the WSM, and the vehicles received them but could not find their ID in the CH list.

I thought the clustering algorithm is not included valid vehicle IDs in the list.

However, when I made the RSU broadcast the WSM only once the vehicles kept becoming CHs, and clusters were formed until the end of the simulation.

So, is this issue because the algorithm stopped giving valid vehicle IDs, or the periodic broadcasting of WSM and WSA is causing severe collisions?